# How to automatically change text in a silverlight textbox?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am using MVVM/Caliburn.Micro in a silverlight 5 project and I have a requirement to automatically change the text the user enters in a silverlight textbox to uppercase.

First, I thought I could just set the backing variable on the ViewModel to uppercase and the two way binding would change the text.  That didn't work (though I believe it will if I use a lost focus event, but I cannot do that since I have other things I must do for KeyUp as well and attaching two events results in a xaml error)

Since that didn't work I tried calling a method on the KeyUp event. This *technically* works, but since it is replacing the text it puts the cursor back at the beginning, so the user ends up typing backwards.

This seems like fairly simple functionality - how do I transform the text a user types into uppercase?  Am I missing something easy?

Here is my existing code.  Xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SomeName" cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyUp] = [Action ConvertToUppercase($eventArgs)]" />
```

View Model:

```
public void ConvertToUppercase(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
     SomeName = _someName.ToUpper();
     //Other code that doesn't concern uppercase
}
```

**EDIT FOR ALTERNATE SOLUTION:**
McAden put forth a nice generic solution.  I also realized at about the same time that there was an alternate solution (just pass the textbox as a param to the uppercase method and move the cursor), so here is the code for that as well:

xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SomeName" cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyUp] = [Action ConvertToUppercase($source, $eventArgs)]; [Event KeyDown] = [Action DoOtherStuffThatIsntQuestionSpecific($eventArgs)]" />
```

cs method:

```
public void ConvertToUppercase(TextBox textBox, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //set our public property here again so the textbox sees the Caliburn.Micro INPC notification fired in the public setter
    SomeName = _someName.ToUpper();

    //move the cursor to the last so the user can keep typing
    textBox.Select(SomeName.Length, 0);
}
```

and of course cs standard Caliburn.Micro property:

```
private String _someName = "";
public String SomeName
{
    get
    {
        return _someName;
    }
    set
    {
        _someName = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SomeName);
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at [`NotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.95).aspx) ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097597/character-casing-in-silverlight-4-textbox

Comment: @Silvermind, - that was what I tried first (exactly like devdigital's suggested answer) but it doesn't reflect the change in the UI

Comment: @McAden - I saw that answer but like I said, I unfortunately have some other code that must be executed on key press and adding two events in the xaml won't compile so that doesn't seem to be an option

Comment: You can attach two EventTriggers to the same event just fine. See my answer as an example.

Comment: When using `NotifyPropertyChanged` have you set the `UpdateTrigger` of the Binding to `OnPropertyChanged` in xaml? Also was the class inherting `INotifyPropertyChanged` happens more so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a ToUpper EventTrigger as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097597/character-casing-in-silverlight-4-textbox). Also create another one for whatever otherfunctionality you're trying to accomplish. Add them both in xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeName, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
            <myBehaviors:UpperCaseAction/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
            <myBehaviors:MyOtherAction/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

**EDIT**: I've fully tested this solution using the following (*NO code-behind is involved*)

UpperCase Action:

```
public class UpperCaseAction : TriggerAction<TextBox>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        var selectionStart = AssociatedObject.SelectionStart;
        var selectionLength = AssociatedObject.SelectionLength;
        AssociatedObject.Text = AssociatedObject.Text.ToUpper();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
        AssociatedObject.SelectionLength = selectionLength;
    }
}
```

Other Action:

```
public class OtherAction : TriggerAction<TextBox>
{
    Random test = new Random();

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        AssociatedObject.FontSize = test.Next(9, 13);
    }
}
```

XAML namespaces (*TestSL in this case being the namespace of my test project - use your namespace as appropriate*):

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSL"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

XAML TextBox

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="LightGray" Width="300" Height="200">
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Width="100">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <local:UpperCaseAction />
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <local:OtherAction />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: OK, I was doing something wrong before but I have called multiple event triggers now.  Using multiple triggers still results in the same problem if I keep using the KeyUp event.  If I switch to using the TextChanged I have problems (no error thrown, but the entered text disappears) since I believe that only works without MVVM (the solution you pointed to uses a codebehind, not a View and ViewModel).

Comment: The link I sent you to shows code-behind if that's the way you want to do it, but the link displays a MVVM example.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the work! I edited my question to show the simplest solution of my problem but I like this better as it is more generic and will probably be easier for people to follow who look at this in the future

Comment: weird, where did that other guy's answer go? Its like he never commented or posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

UpperCaseConverter.cs:

```
namespace MyProject.Converters
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A upper case converter for string values.
        /// </summary>
        public class UpperCaseConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                return ConvertToUpper(value);
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                return ConvertToUpper(value);
            }

            private string ConvertToUpper(object value)
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    return value.ToString().ToUpper();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

AppResources.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters;assembly=MyProject"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >

    <!-- Converters -->
    <conv:UpperCaseConverter x:Key="UpperCaseConverter"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

MyFormView.xaml:

```
<UserControl>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding myText, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource UpperCaseConverter}}" />
</UserControl>
```