# How to search and replace text in TextBox real time

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I am about to develop a text editing app for Windows Phone. In this app the user can enter codes that will be replaced automatically. For instance: when the user enters `td` the app will replace it with `today`. This replacement will occur as soon as the user enters a whitespace after the code.

When I was thinking over this app, I wondered: how am I going to realize this in a proper manner? By proper I mean: adhering to the MVVM-pattern.

Surely, I can bind a `TextBox` to a property in the `ViewModel` and update the property on every change (for instance by using the [Coding4Fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) or updating the binding source using a [`BindingExpression`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833100/updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-equivalent-for-a-windows-phone-7-textbox)). But how am I going to position the caret correctly after a code has been replaced?

Or would it be better to use a `Command` for this? That way I could command the `ViewModel` to change the text, supply the current position and let the `Command` reply with a `Message` containing the new text and the updated position. This will cause rather heavy traffic between `View` and `ViewModel` I'm afraid.

I also found a [nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038909/how-to-automatically-change-text-in-a-silverlight-textbox) using an `EventTrigger` on the `TextBox`. But a drawback of this solution is that the logic for replacing codes is called by the `View` while it should be called by the `ViewModel`.

What say you?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the size of the replacement, pass along, and put the carat accordingly. this seems to be the best solution, in my limited knowledge..

Comment: What do you mean by passing the size along? Who is passing along? The ViewModel? How should I pass it along? With a Message? Or a bound property on the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add binding property updateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" (Winrt). It doesn't exist in wp8 so use updateSourceTrigger="Explicit" like this => [UpdateSourceTrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833100/updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-equivalent-for-a-windows-phone-7-textbox)

Set position with : `"yourTextbox".SelectionStart("yourTextbox".Text.lenght - 1)`

Comment: I know how to do that. In my question I already refer to the question you mention. The problem is, when I use this solution the caret will be at the start of the text. That's not what I want, I want the caret to be positioned right after the replaced code.

Comment: That only works when the code I replace is at the end of the text. When I insert a code somewhere else I need to position the caret mid text.

Comment: So you need to know the selectionStart à the beginning of text_Changed and set selectionStart et the end. For exemple if selectionStart value is 2 at the begginning and you add 2 charactere. Set selectionStart to SelectionStart = selectionStart(your local variable) + 2;